# Can you force a celery scheduled task to run immediately on apply_sync?

Tags: python, celery

I have a scheduled task on Celery which runs after every three minutes. However, in some cases I'd want to run the task immediately when a high priority task comes in.

E.g. You have a schedule to send batch emails every 3 minutes. However, when a high priority email comes in, I'd want to call `send_email.apply_async()` and run it immediately and send that specific high priority email only and exit.

What I've noticed is that when I call `send_email.apply_async(kwargs=hig_priority_email_details)`, I notice that it is not being executed immediately and its like its being sent to run after the 3 minutes. What could I be missing?

The scheduled task:

```
'engine.app_engine_v1_0.send_email.run-every-180-seconds': 
    {'task': 'engine.app_engine_v1_0.send_email',
     'schedule': timedelta(seconds=180),
     'kwargs': {'no_of_emails':60000, 'lock_expire':5, 'skip_lock':False}
     },
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had not ran the `.delay()` method which Celery offers for such a while that I forgot about it. Its explained in the [Celery Basics guide](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html). Its a Shortcut to send a task message, but it does not support execution options.

So in this case, all I needed to do was call `send_email.delay(**high_priority_email_details)` and it will be ran immediately.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to run a task immediately while conserving execution options?

Comment: This will **not** guarantee the task gets run immediately.  `.delay()` just map to `.apply_async()`.  If the task is scheduled with something like `celery.schedules.crontab`, even using `.apply_async(countdown=0)` will not guarantee immediate execution.